# i get internal server error when i try to post some data , can anyone please tell me the error in the code

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

app.post("/addoncategories/post", (req, res) => {
const filepath = path.join(
"inventoryServiceDump(1)/inventoryServiceDump/inventoryService.addoncategories.json"
);
const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filepath, "utf8"));
console.log(filepath);`your text`
const formattedData = jsonData.map((item) => {
const objectIdStr = item._id.$oid;
const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(objectIdStr);
return { ...item, _id: objectId };
});

```
AddonCategory.insertMany(formattedData)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(
            `${result.length} documents inserted into categoeies collection`
        );
        res.send(
            `${result.length} documents inserted into Categories collection`
        );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    });
```

});

Comment: Please share more details, like the exact error message you are facing, along with your attempts to resolve the problem